# Elixir/Phoenix - HTML form parsing in the controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an HTML form:

```
<form id="filtering-rule-form">
<input type="hidden" value="<%= @token %>" name="_csrf_token"/>

User name/email prefix:<br>
<input type="text" name="email-prefix" id="email-prefix">@railglorg.net<br>
Scanner<br>
    <%= for scanner <- @scanners do %>
        <input type="checkbox" id="<%= scanner.short_name %>" value="<%= scanner.short_name %>" name="scanner[]" /><%= scanner.scanner_name %> <br>
    <% end %>

Subject<br>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"><br>
Quarantine score threshold:<br>
<input type="text" name="quarantine-score" id="quarantine-score"><br>
Delete score threshold:<br>
<input type="text" name="delete-score" id="delete-score"><br>
Reject:<br>
<input type="radio" name="reject" value="reject" id="reject-reject" checked > Reject<br>
<input type="radio" name="reject" value="delete" id="reject-delete" > Delete<br>
<button type="button" id="filtering-rule-save-btn">Save</button>
</form>
```

Data from it is transmitted to the controller via an ajax request.

```
$('#filtering-rule-save-btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/configuration/filtering_rule_save',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': jQuery('input[name=_csrf_token]').val()},
        data: {
            filtering_rule_form_data: $("#filtering-rule-form").serialize()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response.message);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert('AJAX ERROR');
        }
    });
});
```

Such a string is passed to the controller.

> _csrf_token=KnNgSz9UKy80eyFdNVoMAFEwDSw9GiE3EFRswlOkR9CiRk9mgWFhtVsp&email-prefix=test&scanner%5B%5D=ps&scanner%5B%5D=clamdscan&subject=test-subject&quarantine-score=5&delete-score=5&reject=reject

[image]

I get this line in the controller.

```
  def filtering_rule_save(conn, %{"filtering_rule_form_data" => filtering_rule_form_data}) do
    #
  end
```

I can’t figure out how to parse all form values ​​in the controller correctly. Please note that the form has an HTML array (scanner[]). I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: Try this: `%{"filtering_rule_form_data" => %{"email-prefix" => email_prefix, ... }}`

Comment: @ipinak Unfortunately this does not work. I get an error:

"no function clause matching in VirusfreeWeb.ConfigurationController.filtering_rule_save/2"

I try this: %{"filtering_rule_form_data" => %{"email-prefix" => email_prefix, "scanner" => scanner, "subject" => subject, "quarantine-score" => q_s, "delete-score" => d_s, "reject" => reject}}

Comment: Just check what is coming with `def filtering_rule_save(conn, data), do: IO.inspect(data)`